# Licensing ASP.NET Web API application by domain and digital signature

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to license an **ASP.NET Web API** application using an [XML Digital Signature](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4940/Using-XML-Digital-Signatures-for-Application-Licen) and restricting it to one domain per license.  `E.g. customerdomain.com`.  I won't use the web to verify the license so it looks like **XML Digital Signatures** are a good way as in the linked article.

I've never had to license any software so I'm not sure XML Digital Signatures are still used or if this approach is outdated?

I also can't figure out how to incorporate the customer-specific **domain** into the **XML Digital Signature** or if that is even possible?